# How can i reuse my symfony entities in a no symfony project

Tags: symfony

I have a some entities in symfony project that I want to reuse in another php project which is not written with symfony. I cannot rewrite this project because, it is to huge.

Is there a way to include my entities and their respositories in a no symfony project ?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: does your other project use doctrine  ?

Comment: It depends on how your repository code is dependent on Symfony components. If you didn't inject any service to your repositories, then you can safely use your entities outside Symfony. You just still need to use the ORM (i.e. Doctrine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested, i have found a solution to use Entity and Repository outside Symfony

For the example, I installed a new Symfony in /path, and I created a simple entity "Testeur"

```
<?php
// Import
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/vendor/autoload.php';
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Testeur;


$paths = array("/path/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Entity/");
$isDevMode = true;

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'dbname'   => 'test_sf',
);

// Creation of the entity manager
$config = Setup::createConfiguration($isDevMode);
$driver = new AnnotationDriver(new AnnotationReader(), $paths);
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists'); // registering noop annotation autoloader - allow all annotations by default
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

// Creation of the repository of my Testeur entity
$metadata            = $entityManager->getClassMetadata('Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Testeur');
$repositoryClassName = $metadata->customRepositoryClassName;
if ($repositoryClassName === null) {
    $configuration       = $entityManager->getConfiguration();
    $repositoryClassName = $configuration->getDefaultRepositoryClassName();
}
/** @var \Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\TesteurRepository $tR */
$repo =  new $repositoryClassName($entityManager, $metadata);

// Example insertion
$obj = new Testeur();
$obj->setLib('First object');
$obj->setDescription('This is my first object');
$obj->setSort(1);
$obj->setVisible(true);
$entityManager->persist($obj);
$entityManager->flush();

// Get an objet by the repo
$o = $repo->find(17);
echo "<pre>".print_r($o, true)."</pre>";
```

So now, with this solution I can use my entities into a huge (shitty) project which is not made with symfony